# Unique filter issue in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Here is my drop down

```
<select name="EType" id="opt-type" class="form-control" 
        ng-options="type.id as type.name for type in types" 
        ng-disabled="!eng.adding" ng-change="TypeChange()"> 
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

I want unique record in combo i tried unique filer after applying that filter all record showing empty data

Can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'unique' filter ([angularUi](https://angular-ui.github.io/))

```
ng-options="type in types| unique:'name'"
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say you tried unique filter then it should work. Kindly cross check below points :

- required modules are added `angular.module('myApp',['ui.directive', 'ui.filters']);`
- angular-ui is referred? `<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>`